# Pascal exit code 201

Tags: input, pascal, freepascal, exit-code

I'm able to compile the program but not able to run it. I need to plug in the N=11, dtmax=0.0003 and do trials with M=11,21,41 and 61. I tried to input values using constants and also by stating them in the writeln but it does not work.

Below in my writeln statements, the values of 11 is where I tried to input them. I don't know what's wrong.

```
uses 
  crt, printer;

const 
  N = 11;       {radial nodes}
  M = 21;       {axial nodes}
  k = 40.0;     {thermal conductivity (W/mK)}
  alpha = 1e-5; {thermal diffusivity (m^2/s)}
  Rs = 0.025;   {disk radius (m)}
  Zs = 0.005;   {disk thickness (m)}
  qmax = 3.0e6; {peak flux (W/m^2)}
  Ro = 0.05;    {parameter in flux equation (m)}
  Tinit = 20.0; {initial temperature (C)}
  Tmax = 300.0; {maximum desired temperature at top of axis (C)}

var 
  dr, dz, rhoC, dtMax, dt, time : real;
  i, j : Longint;
  C, R, L, U, D : array [1..N,1..M] of real;
  q, V, Aco, Aci, Af : array [1..N] of real;
  Told, Tnew : array [1..N+1,1..M+1] of real;

begin
  {Size of the control volumes}
  dr := Rs/(N - 1);
  dz := Zs/(M - 1);
  rhoC:= k/alpha;
  {Control volume surface areas and volumes}
  Af[1] := pi*dr*dr/4.0;
  Af[N] := pi*dr*(Rs - dr/4.0);

  for i := 2 to N - 1 do 
    Af[i] := 2.0*pi*dr*dr*(i - 1);

  for i := 1 to N do 
    V[i] := Af[i]*dz;

  Aco[N] := 2.0*pi*Rs*dz;

  for i := 1 to N - 1 do 
    Aco[i] := 2.0*pi*dr*dz*(i - 0.5);

  Aci[1] := 0.0;

  for i := 2 to N do 
    Aci[i] := 2.0*pi*dr*dz*(i - 1.5);
 
  {Absorbed flux as function of i}
  q [1] := pi/4.0*qmax*dr*dr*(1.0 - 0.9/8.0*sqr(dr/Ro));
  q [N] := pi*qmax*dr*dr*(N - 1.25-0.9/8.0*sqr(dr/Ro)*(2.0*N*N*N -7.5*N*N
+ 9.5*N - 65.0/16.0));

  for i := 2 to N - 1 do
    q [i] := pi*qmax*dr*dr*(2.0*(1 - 1.0) - 0.9/4.0*sqr(dr/Ro)*(4.0*i*i*i - 12.0*i*

  i + 13.0*i - 5.0));
  {Coefficient matrices}
  for i := 1 to N do 
    for j := 1 to M do
    begin
      R[i, j] := 0.0;
      L[i, j] := 0.0;
      U[i, j] := 0.0;
      D[i, j] := 0.0;
      C[i, j] := 0.0;
    end;

  For i := 2 to N - 1 do
    For j := 2 to M - 1 do
    begin;
      R[i, j] := Aco[i]/dr;
      L[i, j] := Aci[i]/dr;
      U[i, j] := Af[i]/dz;
      D[i, j] := Af[i]/dz;
    end;

  i := 1;
  for j := 2 to M - 1 do
  begin
    R[i, j] := Aco[i]/dr;
    U[i, j] := Af[i]/dz;
    D[i, j] := Af[i]/dz;
  end;
  
  i := 1;
  j := M;
  R[i, j] := Aco[i]/dr;
  D[i, j] := Af[i]/dz;
  i := 1;
  j := 1;
  R[i, j] := Aco[i]/dr;
  U[i, j] := Af[i]/dz;

  i := N;
  for j := 2 to M - 1 do
  begin
    L[i, j] := Aci[i]/dr;
    U[i, j] := Af[i]/dz;
    D[i, j] := Af[i]/dz;
  end;

  i := N;
  j := M;
  L[i, j] := Aci[i]/dr;
  D[i, j] := Af[i]/dz;
  i := N;
  j := 1;
  L[i, j] := Aci[i]/dr;
  U[i, j] := Af[i]/dz;
  j := M;
  
  for I := 2 to N - 1 do
  begin
    R[i, j] := Aco[i]/dr;
    L[i, j] := Aci[i]/dr;
    D [i, j] := Af[i]/dz;
  end;

  j := 1;
  for I := 2 to N - 1 do
  begin
    R [i, j] := Aco[i]/dr;
    L [i, j] := Aci[i]/dr;
    U [i, j] := Af[i]/dz;
  end;

  {Maximum permissible dt}
  dtMax := 0.0;
  for i := 1 to N do
    for j := 1 to M do
    begin
      dt := V[i]/alpha/(R[i, j] + L[i, j] + U[i, j] + D[i, j]);
      if dt > dtMax then 
        dtMax := dt;
    end;

  dt := 0.5*dtMax; {actual value}
  {fill in the cij matrix}
  for i := 1 to N do 
    C[1, M] := dt*q [i]/rhoC/V[i];

  {Initial conditions}
  for i := 1 to N do
    for j := 1 to M do
      Told [i, j] := Tinit;
 
  {carry out the solution}
  time := 0.0;
  repeat
    time:= time + dt;
    writeln (time: 10:5);

    for i:= 1 to N do
      for j:= 1 to M do
        Tnew [i,j] := Told [i,j]*(1.0 - alpha*dt/V[i]*(R[i,j]+ L[i,j]+ U[i,j]+
D[i,j])
+ alpha*dt/V[i]*(R[i, j]*Told [i + 1, j] + L[i, j]*Told [i - 1, j] + U[i, j]*Told
[i, j + 1] + D[i, j]*Told [i, j - 1]) + C[i, j]);

    if Tnew[1,m] > Tmax then {print out distribution and quit}
    begin
      writeln(11, time : 8 : 4, 'sec dt =', dt : 15 : 10);
      write(11,' ');

      for i := 1 to N do 
        write (11, 1 : 10);

      writeln(11);

      for j := M downto 1 do
      begin
        write(11, j : 4);

        for i := 1 to N do 
          write(11, Tnew[i,j]: 10 : 5);

        writeln(11);
      end;
 
      writeln(11);
      halt;
    end;
 
    for i := 1 to N do
      for j := 1 to M do
        Told[i, j]:= Tnew[i, j];
  until time < - 1.0;

end.
```

I looked up how to debug exit code 201 and changed the integer to Longin but it didn't solve it. I tried to plug in values in the writeln statements but it doesn't work. I'm able to see a screen pop up but I cant read it since it disappears.

Comment: I get an error here: write(1st,' '); - who is 1st?

Comment: oh that was met to replace the 1st value for the run which is 11.

Comment: I edited the code and replaced it with 11, the 1st was intended for the prompt to ask for the 1st value.

Comment: works fine. tested on https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_pascal_compiler. No errors

Comment: It runs on that website but it gives me the same values even after changing the M value

Comment: I don't know how I can help u further. U should understand the algorithm and see what M does and why your results stay the same.

Comment: okay thank you, I'm not use to the online compiler nor the command window, thanks for the help

Comment: Use a debugger and step through your program. Always do that first when your program doesn't behave how you expect. You can't hope for success without knowing how to debug.

Comment: The assignment on about line 157 has at two array bounds errors:
    1) Told [i - 1, j] is an error because when i is 1 then i-1 is 0 but Told is defined as Told, Tnew : array [1..N_PLUS_1,1..M_PLUS_1] of real;
    2) Told [i, j - 1] is also an error for the same reason (i.e. j-1 is zero when j is 1).